# How can open viewcontroller immediately on click on button

Tags: iphone

I am developing an e-com app for iPhone in which i need to open a view immediately when the user clicks on a button for the upcoming view, the data loads large images from server , to load images I am using a background thread .

Thank You

Comment: Depends on your navigation structure you can use: [self.navigationController pushViewController: YOURVIEWCONTROLLER](1) or [self presentModalViewController:YOURVIEWCONTROLLER animated:YES](2) or [self.view addSubview:YOURVIEW](3)  - the first requires that your root controller is a UINavigationController, the second second be called in any viewController, the last one only adds the view without any controlling

Answer (score 5):

Simple, here's how to create a `UIViewController` and present it from within an `IBAction`.

```
- (IBAction)goToNextView:(id)sender
    {
     //if you are using xibs use this line
        UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myXib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    //if you are using storyboards use this line
        UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllersID"];

    //to present the controller modally use this
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
    //or if you are pushing to this controller using a navigation controller use this
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
    }
```

Be sure to pass animated `NO` so that the view is displayed immediately.

Comment: NSPostWhenIdle Thanks for reply ,i am dong same thing .. in my app loading big image from web server .. the network request code , i written inside viewWillAppear . but untill data is not received from server it show progress in same screen . i want open immediately next view window on click

Comment: @JackFarnandish If my post has helped you be sure to mark it as correct by clicking the "check mark" next to my post! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use modal view controller for this

```
- (IBAction)showController:(id)sender {
    SampleViewController *sampleView = [[SampleViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
}
```

Here it is the tutorial http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a button and then add its action like

```
-(IBAction)ButtonAction:(id)sender{

CalController *calculateView=[[CalController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:calculateView animated:NO];
```

}